# Sourcing a cmd file with ''call'' from Windows cmder

Tags: cmd, cmder

Forced to use Windows, after 4 years on Linux, I am trying to get used to [cmder](https://github.com/cmderdev).
I want to integrate `ssh-agent` and `pageant`, but I am facing basic problems.

When [call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) is used in `config/user-profile.cmd`, colors and other stuff are gone.
It seems `call` is not sourcing the file as I expected.
Shouldn't `call` execute the .cmd file seamlessly?

[image]
[image]

More details can be found here: https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1963